# What does pipeline after ^ does in a bash regex?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a very simple sequence of bash commands:

```
echo "output 3:"
echo "abc shalom" >|F1
echo " abc shalom 4" >> F1
echo "abc shalom12" >> F1
echo "abc shalom123 shalom6" >> F1
echo "abcshalom22 456 shalom" >> F1
egrep "(^|[ ]*)[^ ]+[ ]+shalom($|..[ ])" F1
```

the output is:

```
abc shalom
abcshalom22 456 shalom
```

I can't understand how this simple regex works, I understand that the pipeline is "or", but I dont understand how do I get those two lines...

Could someone please explain me step by step what happened in this short regex?

Comment: Not to get off track but it's called a "pipe" not a pipeline but it is a line called a pipe so does anyone call it a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see:

```
egrep "(^|[ ]*)[^ ]+[ ]+shalom($|..[ ])" F1
```

`|` indicates to match either one thing or another. Hence, `aa|bb` means: match either `aa` or `bb`.

Saying `^|[ ]*` you are using a regex to match either the beginning of the line (represented by `^`) or a sequence of zero or more spaces (represented by `[ ]*`).